# Display certain posts based on User Location

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, search

I'm trying to figure out how to display certain mongoDB posts depending on the user's location. I have set up a search functionality that lets people search for MongoDB posts. I also have figured out how to get a user's location and find a big city near them.

Let's say you're in Washington DC. I want only posts containing Washington DC in the title to show up on a "show" page. I've been unable to figure this out.

Any advice?

Thanks!

### Node & MongoDB set up to handle search request:

```
router.get("/", function(req, res){
     if (req.query.search) {
          const regex = new RegExp(req.query.search, 'i');
          Deals.find({ "name": regex }, function(err, founddeals) {
          if(err){
              console.log(err);
          } else {
              res.render("deals/index",{deals:founddeals});
          }
     }); 
}
```

### Set up to get the user's location.

This also returns the city nearest to the user

```
// Get User's Coordinate from their Browser
window.onload = function() {
  // HTML5/W3C Geolocation
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(UserLocation);
  }
  // Default to Washington, DC
  else
    NearestCity(38.8951, -77.0367);
}

// Callback function for asynchronous call to HTML5 geolocation
function UserLocation(position) {
  NearestCity(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
}


// Convert Degress to Radians
function Deg2Rad(deg) {
  return deg * Math.PI / 180;
}

function PythagorasEquirectangular(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
  lat1 = Deg2Rad(lat1);
  lat2 = Deg2Rad(lat2);
  lon1 = Deg2Rad(lon1);
  lon2 = Deg2Rad(lon2);
  var R = 6371; // km
  var x = (lon2 - lon1) * Math.cos((lat1 + lat2) / 2);
  var y = (lat2 - lat1);
  var d = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y) * R;
  return d;
}

var lat = 20; // user's latitude
var lon = 40; // user's longitude

var cities = [
  ["ATL", 33.740231, -84.394521],
  ["NYC", 40.748163, -73.985946],
  ["Vegas", 34.825425, -82.545665]

];

function NearestCity(latitude, longitude) {
  var mindif = 99999;
  var closest;

  for (index = 0; index < cities.length; ++index) {
    var dif = PythagorasEquirectangular(latitude, longitude, cities[index][1], cities[index][2]);
    if (dif < mindif) {
      closest = index;
      mindif = dif;
    }
  }

  // echo the nearest city
  alert(cities[closest]);
  console.log(closest)



}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I Hope you are using mongoose. Please try this code in your server. I have used $regex and made a small modification for your code.

```
router.get("/", function(req, res){
     if (req.query.search) {
          Deals.find({ "name":{ $regex: req.query.search } }, function(err, founddeals) {
          if(err){
              console.log(err);
          } else {
              res.render("deals/index",{deals:founddeals});
          }
        }); 
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @IsettyRavitejakumar! Can you explain a little what this change does? Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewLeonardi I used $regex operator to get the job done. It  provides regular expression capabilities for pattern matching strings in queries. for more info refer this docs. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

Comment: @AndrewLeonardi  Let me know it worked for you or not.